Why are Maps allowed where an OrderedMap is expected? (TypeScript API Design Question)
To clarify: This is nominally about Immutable.js' Map/OrderedMap, though the essence of the question is general to any TypeScript API (/structurally typed language).
I think I understand technically why in effect Map<K,V> extends OrderedMap<K,V> holds, despite it never being written in the source code (only the other way round):
TypeScript's structural typing dictates that, as objects of types Map and OrderedMap have the exact same outwardly visible properties/methods (fields), and these fields have the same (generic) types, Map and OrderedMap are actually considered the same type.
But in practice, there's more to the contracts of these datatypes than the fields and their types. OrderedMap guarantees iteration order being the insertion order, while Map doesn't. This should make OrderedMap a proper subtype of Map - i.e. an OrderedMap object fullfills the contract of a Map object, but not the other way round.
One could could easily make the typechecker "understand" this - and highlight code where an OrderedMap is expected but a Map is provided - by adding something like a "isOrderedMap: true" field to OrderedMap.
Shouldn't this be done? Are there valid drawbacks to this tightening of type compile-time safety?

this is really an Immutable specific issue and not typescript. From the source: "The iteration behavior of OrderedMap is the same as native ES6 Map" and TypeScript has built in support for ES6 Maps github. Adding isOrderedMap as a bool isn't correct either since isOrderedMap is a static method on Immutable OrderedMap

• "tightening of type safety" It's not type safety though, if the restriction has nothing to do with the fields and their types (or at least not structural type safety, which is mostly all TS cares about.)  Maybe you could [edit] to say something like "emulating nominal typing" or "adding a nonstructural restriction" instead of "type safety"?

@pilchard I updated the question to make it clear I'm ostensibly talking about Immutable's data structures. But I feel the essence of the question does apply to TS more generally, so I've kept the 'typescript' tag. Regarding calling the field 'isOrderedMap':  I had to check myself, but same-name static fields and instance fields can coexist, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-xpvfk7?file=src%2Fmain.ts

@jcalz You're right that it's not type safety in the narrow(est) sense, I opted for a different phrasing.
